# Ember.js - Adding a sequential id for fixtures

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've created some dummy content and let ember specify the id and created a Ember Business object like so:

```
Yrf.Business = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    rating_img_url: DS.attr('image'),
    is_closed: DS.attr('boolean'),
    address1: DS.attr('string'),
    address2: DS.attr('string'),
    phone: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    photo_url: DS.attr('image')
});
```

From there i import dummy Yelp Json and create a fixture out of it

```
Yrf.Business.FIXTURES = [{...}] // Data goes here
```

Now when i do this ember decides to create an id for me. Here's an example of one

`xSKEe6upPy-pFkLAW1O5uw`.

How do i change the Id's to make them sequential and start at 0 (e.g. 0-9999) ? I need to be able to reference them like so:

```
this.store.find('Business', 1); // Get item 1 in my model
this.store.find('Business',35234);
this.store.find('Business',randomInteger);
```

In the end, i'd like to generate a random number and grab a single item from my Fixtures.

Comment: This is just an idea. May be extending the adapter and overriding the `generateIdForRecord` method might work. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.8/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L126

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, did you think about doing something like this:

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
  .find('yourModelName').then(function(yourModelName) {
    var ids = yourModelName.getEach('id'));
    return _.sample(ids) // http://underscorejs.org/#sample
  });
```

So in your route:

```
model: function() {
  this.store.findAll('yourModelName');
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
randomBusinessId: function() {
  var ids = this.getEach('id');
  return _.sample(ids); // http://underscorejs.org/#sample
}.property('model.[]'),


randomBusiness: function() {
  return this.objectAt(this.get('randomBusinessId'));
}.property('randomBusinessId')
```

There's a bunch of untested code in here but I hope it can be of help for you!